# GPUImage swift iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, swift, gpuimage

Does anybody released app with Swift and GPUImage for iOS 7+ ?
When I trying to post an app I'm getting error (it isn't my screen, but I getting the same)

[image]

App worked perfect on all devices and simulators for ios 7, also I sent it as adhoc via testflight and it still worked, but I can't release it now.

Comment: How did you include both libraries? What I mean are you using precompiled version or are you downloading source? Or better yet cocoa pods.

Comment: GPUImage: https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage#adding-this-as-a-framework-module-to-your-mac-or-ios-project and Alamofire: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#installation but I need to fix GPUImage only, because I will replace Alamofire with AFNetworking

Comment: As I know there is no cocoa pods for swift

Comment: Seem to sort of work, but the issue is the swift is using the shared library for GPUImage, which is build for iOS 8 or higher. You will to change it to be iOS 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the root problem here is the support for embedded frameworks. To make an Objective-C framework like GPUImage available to Swift projects, you have to build it as a module, which first requires it to be built as a full bundled framework. I set this up for GPUImage so that it could be used in a Swift project.

Support for bundled frameworks (instead of the static libraries we have been using), is new to iOS 8, but you can run locally and even ad hoc deploy iOS applications using bundled frameworks back to iOS 7 (the Mac has of course supported this from the beginning). My FilterShowcaseSwift sample application using GPUImage works well on iOS 7, for example.

However, it sounds like the App Store is rejecting applications using bundled frameworks which target iOS versions earlier than 8. I don't know if there's a way around this, because again you can run these applications just fine in iOS 7. This may also be a temporary thing, because I've heard there have been issues with even iOS 8-only applications using bundled frameworks on the App Store.

Maybe you could manually add GPUImage classes to your project and use a bridging header to avoid the need for the framework itself, but that sounds like a mess.

Comment: Thank you @Brad, your advice was helpfull. I did't release app yet but now it works without GPUImage.framework, I included all files to my project and used bridge. Thank you for your framework :)

Comment: Is there any better workaround yet? I have tried out using the objective-c version of the library, which can work if I add the framework path in the header search path field, but it causes a weird bug and crashes Xcode if I set a breakpoint. Anyway, copying the sources manually works for me too.